# Replace comma with double quotes enclosed comma for all character fields?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my schema, for a definite set of tables, if any character field contains a comma it must be enclosed in double quotes.How can I achieve this for all the character fields of that set of tables in one go.I am using Oracle 11g?

Comment: In one go? What is it, one UPDATE statement? I'm not sure it'll work. A procedure which utilizes dynamic SQL - yes, probably so.

Comment: It sounds like you're creating a csv inside your database. If that's not what you're doing then ignore me, however, if you are I would stop and only perform operations necessary to create a csv during the extract of your data (i.e. don't modify the data in your database)

Comment: And if you are just creating a CSV output, consider existing options - e.g. SQL Developer and SQLcl have built-in tools that make this trivial, and I'm sure other clients do too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm following the question correctly, but maybe this will give you what you need.

Create our example table:

```
create table foobar (foo varchar2(30));
```

Populate it with test values:

```
insert into foobar values ('There is no comma.');
insert into foobar values ('There is, a comma.');
```

This query will wrap comma-containing values in double-quotes:

```
select decode(instr(foo,','),0,foo,'"'||foo||'"') from foobar;
```

And here's the output:

```
"There is, a comma."
There is no comma.
```

Here's how it works.  The INSTR tests for the presence of a comma in the column. If there is no comma (INSTR returns 0) the DECODE returns the column as is. In all other circumstances (i.e. a comma exists) we wrap the output in double-quotes.

Repeat for each table/column.

It would be simple to use the syntax in an update statement, if that's what you're trying to achieve.  So,

```
update foobar 
set foo=decode(instr(foo,','),0,foo,'"'||foo||'"');
```